# X Ray Scraper: Manipulate data before .write

Tags: scrape, x-ray

I'm fiddling around with some scraping, and need to manipulate some of the data before writing it to my json file.

```js
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();


x('http://myUrl.com', '#search_results div div a', [{
    title: '.responsive_search_name_combined .search_name .title',
    price: '.col.search_price.responsive_secondrow',
}])

.paginate('.search_pagination_right a.pagebtn:last-child@href')
    .limit(10)
    .write('data.json');
```

When saved, price looks like this: "price": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t13,99€\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".

I guess its because theres a lot of spaces in div.col.search_price.responsive_secondrow.

```html
<div class="col search_price  responsive_secondrow">
        9,99€       </div>
```

So my question is: Would it be possible to manipulate the data before .write?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can simply provide a callback function that takes an object which is the result of your scrape. In this function you can take full control of any post-processing you want to do.

So your code would end up something like:

```js
x('http://myUrl.com', '#search_results div div a', [{
        title: '.responsive_search_name_combined .search_name .title',
        price: '.col.search_price.responsive_secondrow',
    }])
(function(products){
     var cleanedProducts = [];
     products.forEach(function(product){
        var cleanedProduct = {};
        cleanedProduct.price = product.price.trim();
        //etc
        cleanedProducts.push(cleanedProduct)
     });

     //write out results.json 'manually'
     fs.writeFile('results.json', JSON.stringify(cleanedProducts));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use X-Ray native supported approach which is called `filter` functions and completely covers the case you described.

`filters` are custom defined functions allowing you to implement custom logic while processing scraped data.

See code sample below. There's a custom defined filter function with name of `cleanUpText` and apply it to scraped data `price`.

```
    var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray({
    filters: {
        cleanUpText: function (value) { return value.replace('\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '').replace('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', ''); },
    }
});


x('http://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers', '#search_results div div a', [{
    title: '.responsive_search_name_combined .search_name .title ',
    price: '.col.search_price.responsive_secondrow | cleanUpText', // calling filter function 'cleanUpText'
}])

    .paginate('.search_pagination_right a.pagebtn:last-child@href')
    .limit(10)
    .write('data.json');
```

`data.json` looks like below:

```
{"title": "PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS",
"price": "$29.99"},
{"title": "PAYDAY 2: Ultimate Edition",
"price": "$44.98"}
```